# Problem with progressEvent Listener

Tags: actionscript-3

```
for (i=0; i < _xmlContents.img_array.length; i++)
{
        _loader = new Loader();
    _loader.name = "image"+i;       
    _loader.load(new URLRequest(_xmlContents.img_array[i]));
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
    //Event.COMPLETE listnere
       //error Handler
}
private function onLoadingAction(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    _preLoader = new Preloader();
    //addChild(_preLoader);
    trace(_loader.name);
}
```

I want to add preloader for every image in the xml. Now I am getting for last image only.
(consider if xml length is 5, it will trace image4 only)

How can I add that?

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out where your `Preloader` object comes into play.

Comment: Just imagine I have 5 images and I have loaded it into movieclips. `mc.x= mc.width*i;` Hope u got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (i=0; i < _xmlContents.img_array.length; i++)
 {
         _loader = new Loader();
    _loader.name = "image"+i;       
    _loader.load(new URLRequest(_xmlContents.img_array[i]));   
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,
     onLoadingAction);
        //Event.COMPLETE listnere
            //error Handler
     _preLoader = new Preloader();
_bgBox.addChild(_preLoader);

 }
```

This way is solves my problem.. But I don't think so, it's a good way.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have one _loader object. In every loop step you overwrite this loader with new one so previous image stops loading. You should use new loaders for every image:

```
for (i=0; i < _xmlContents.img_array.length; i++)
{
    // create new loader instance, not use a global one
    var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
    _loader.name = "image"+i; 
    _loader.load(new URLRequest(_xmlContents.img_array[i]));
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
    //Event.COMPLETE listnere
    //error Handler

    _preLoader = new Preloader();
    //addChild(_preLoader);
}
private function onLoadingAction(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    // trace(e.bytesLoaded, e.bytesTotal);

}
```

Comment: `Error: Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information.
 at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get loader()
 at Main/::onLoadingAction()`
I got this error for `var _loader:Loader = e.target.loader;`

Comment: ok, my mistake, I see that progressevent doesn't have target.loader property so this won't work, but do you need loader name property in progress event handler? Also you should create and add preloaders in your first loop, not in this event handler - this handler calls every time when progress is made so it's called many times and you want to add one preloader per image

Comment: @Bartek instantiating a variable in a loop creates multiple instances, and they can be accessed IN THE LOOP with the same name. So `_loader` in this case will refer to the loader object instantiated in this iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the array is necessary and I think you'll be on a better track adding 4 instances of the preloader by calling it from `Event.INIT` as opposed to repeatedly adding it by using `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your event listeners attached to the loader instances before the last one (e.g. loaders 0 to 3) are there. They will still be there for a long long time. Remove them!

ActionScript is a very nice language - use it's power :)

```
for (i=0; i < img_array.length; i++)
{
    _loader = new Loader();
    _loader.name = "image"+i;
    _loader.load(new URLRequest(img_array[i]));
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, 
        function onLoadingAction(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace((e.target as LoaderInfo).loader.name);
            //Do whatever you want to do here like removing event listener
            if ((e.target as LoaderInfo).bytesLoaded == (e.target as LoaderInfo).bytesTotal)
            {
                (e.target as LoaderInfo).removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
                trace("Event listener for " + (e.target as LoaderInfo).loader.name + " removed ");
            }

    }, false, i * 1000 /* you can use priority if want to maintain some order in event handling*/);
}
```

ActionScript provides you with the ability to name inline functions and to have a reference to them. Use this approach when you don't need to keep a reference to some object.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score -1):

You your _loader object is defined inside the function and not referenced anywhere else, so it is garbage collected after the function ends. Create an array of loaders and push the loaders to them each time.

```
private var _loadersArray:Array=[]; //outside the function

for (i=0; i < _xmlContents.img_array.length; i++)
{
    // create new loader instance, not use a global one
    var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
    _loader.name = "image"+i; 
    _loader.load(new URLRequest(_xmlContents.img_array[i]));
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
    _loadersArray.push(_loader);
    //Event.COMPLETE listnere
    //error Handler
}
private function onLoadingAction(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    _preLoader = new Preloader();
    //addChild(_preLoader);
    // get current loader instance
    var _loader:Loader = e.target.loader;
    trace(_loader.name);
}
```

Comment: Objects doesn't get removed from memory until you have any references to them, for example eventListeners so it's not garbage collected. So you don't need to store them in an array

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: What is the need for store the loaders in an array?

Comment: Well, for some strange reason I have experienced that if I do not have a reference to the loader (in an array or in a separate variable) the events fire VERY randomly

Comment: @Bartek the `Timer` could still be garbage-collected, even with listeners because all EventDispatcher objects maintain the list of handler callbacks themselves.