# ActionScript 3.0 How to create ProgressEvent instances in for loop with multiple files loaded from XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, for-loop, progress, preloader

Since I developing some app I encounter some problems with ProgressEvent.PROGRESS. I try to assign this event do every image that is loaded from XML data. Every single image that is last called properly preloads. The thing is that every previous doesn't. I tried to figure out this solution: 
[Problem with progressEvent Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554788/problem-with-progressevent-listener) but probably i make error somewhere.

This is my code:

```
var total_columns_preview = myXML.table[companyNumber].column.length();         
for (var p:int=0; p < total_columns_preview; p++) 
{

    var foto_nest:String = myXML.table[companyNumber].column[p].@name.toString();   
    var foto_name:String = myXML.table[companyNumber].column[p].toString(); 
    if (foto_nest == "foto") 
    {
        var foto_icon_mc = new image(); 
        images_container_mc.addChild(foto_icon_mc);
            if (foto_name != "") {

        var varrLoadersFoto:Loader = new Loader();
            varrLoadersFoto.name = "image"+p; 
            varrLoadersFoto.load(new URLRequest("igwodociagi/min_pic/min/"+foto_name));
            varrLoadersFoto.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressLoadFoto);
            varrLoadersFoto.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFotoLoaded);
            foto_icon_mc.photo_container.addChild(varrLoadersFoto);                                         
                var preloader:MovieClip = new preloader_mc();
                foto_icon_mc.addChild(preloader);                               
                images_container_mc.addChild(foto_icon_mc);

            }               
    }   
}

    function onFotoLoaded(event:Event) {

            event.target.content.smoothing = true;
            preloader_foto_dimm = new Tween(preloader, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 0.6, true);
            immage_foto_undim = new Tween(event.target.content, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 0.6, true);


    }               

    function progressLoadFoto(e:ProgressEvent) {

            var percent:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100;
            preloader.logo_preload.text = (Math.floor(percent) / 100) + "%";                                                        
            preloader.preload_box.scaleX = (Math.floor(percent) / 100);


    }
```

My question is how to assign event separately to every image so preloader will update for each one of the images.

Comment: in `progressLoadFoto` function what is `preloader` exactly ? some global object?

Comment: yes this is global object (movie clip) added from library

Comment: but if so , you display every images' loading data simultaneously in one text field, because you start to load them all together at once

Comment: does it mean that I have to load them separatly? if that is the case how to?

Comment: do not load them in `for` loop , instead of it load each next after `onFotoLoaded` of previous one

Comment: Aright, your advice get me some results, I will post working code bellow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok for someone who seek resolution this is realization of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206613/cherniv 's advice I followed. 
"do not load them in for loop , instead of it load each next after onFotoLoaded of previous one"

```
    var total_columns_preview = myXML.table[companyNumber].column.length();
for (var p:int=0; p < total_columns_preview; p++){
    var foto_nest:String = myXML.table[companyNumber].column[p].@name.toString();
    var foto_name:String = myXML.table[companyNumber].column[p].toString();
    if (foto_nest == "foto"){
        //loading object from library
        var foto_icon_mc = new image(); 
        loadPictures();
    }
}
function loadPictures(){
    var varLoadersFoto:Loader = new Loader();
        varLoadersFoto.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initLoadFoto);
        varLoadersFoto.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressLoadFoto);
        varLoadersFoto.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedFoto);
        varLoadersFoto.load(new URLRequest("igwodociagi/min_pic/min/"+foto_name));
        foto_icon_mc.photo_container.addChild(varLoadersFoto);
            //loading preloader object from library
            var preloader:MovieClip = new preloader_mc(); 
            foto_icon_mc.addChild(preloader);
    function initLoadFoto(e:Event):void{
        //here i place where photo should be visible (x, y - possition)
    }
    function progressLoadFoto(e:ProgressEvent){
        var percent:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100;
        preloader.logo_preload.text = (Math.floor(percent) / 100) + "%";
        preloader.preload_box.scaleX = (Math.floor(percent) / 100);
    }
    function onLoadedFoto(e:Event){
        //smoothing loaded content (bitmap) if dimentions of loaded file are too big
        e.target.content.smoothing = true; 
        preloader_foto_dimm = new Tween(preloader,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,0.6,true);
        immage_foto_undim = new Tween(e.target.content,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,0.6,true);
    }
}
```

Thank you. Hope that help some one.